# Cordova push notification actions

Tags: ios, cordova, notifications

Cordova certainly has options for sending push notifications, but do any of the plugins include the ability to add actions directly to the notification?

I tried searching for 'interactive notification' and 'notification action' plugins, but yielded no results. I also tried taking a look at the [API reference for phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md) but found no suitable options or methods.

An example of what I'm looking for is what happens when iMessage allows users to respond to texts without even opening the app:

[image: iOS push notification action]

Can any Cordova plugins add actions to push notifications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your notification can include action buttons. For iOS 8+ you must setup the possible actions when you initialize the plugin:

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
    "ios": {
        "sound": true,
        "vibration": true,
        "badge": true,
        "categories": {
            "invite": {
                "yes": {
                    "callback": "app.accept", "title": "Accept", "foreground": true, "destructive": false
                },
                "no": {
                    "callback": "app.reject", "title": "Reject", "foreground": true, "destructive": false
                },
                "maybe": {
                    "callback": "app.maybe", "title": "Maybe", "foreground": true, "destructive": false
                }
            },
            "delete": {
                "yes": {
                    "callback": "app.doDelete", "title": "Delete", "foreground": true, "destructive": true
                },
                "no": {
                    "callback": "app.cancel", "title": "Cancel", "foreground": true, "destructive": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You’ll notice that we’ve added a new parameter to the iOS object of our init code called categories. Each category is a named object, invite and delete in this case. These names will need to match the one you send via your payload to APNS if you want the action buttons to be displayed. Each category can have up to three buttons which must be labeled yes, no and maybe. In turn each of these buttons has four properties, callback the javascript function you want to call, title the label for the button, foreground whether or not to bring your app to the foreground and destructive which doesn’t actually do anything destructive it just colors the button red as a warning to the user that the action may be destructive.

Just like with background notifications it is absolutely critical that you call push.finish() when you have successfully processed the button callback. For instance:

```
app.accept = function(data) {
    // do something with the notification data

    push.finish(function() {
        console.log('accept callback finished');
    }, function() {
        console.log('accept callback failed');
    }, data.additionalData.notId);    
};
```

You may notice that the finish method now takes success, failure and id parameters. The id parameter let's the operating system know which background process to stop. You'll set it in the next step.

Then you will need to set the category value in your aps payload to match one of the objects in the categories object. As well you should set a notId property in the root of payload object. This is the parameter you pass to the finish method in order to tell the operating system that the processing of the push event is done.

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "This is a notification that will be displayed ASAP.",
        "category": "invite"
    },
    "notId": "1"
}
```

If your users clicks on the main body of the notification your app will be opened. However if they click on either of the action buttons the app will open (or start) and the specified JavaScript callback will be executed.

```
Note: Action buttons are only supported on iOS when you send directly to APNS. If you are using GCM to send to iOS devices you will lose this functionality.
```

I just pasted the documentation on https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#action-buttons-1

Comment: Great this is just what I was looking for. Thanks for the in-depth explanation.

Comment: I just copied the docs. I'll open an issue on the plugin repo to point that this should be mentioned on the API.md and not just on the PAYLOAD.md